# Where i can find log for magento api?

Tags: api, magento

I created Attributes with Options and Set.
And when i create products it's return faultMessages = "Internal Error. Please see log for details.".

**Wrere I can find this log?**
in **var/log** and **var/api** i not find it's
[image]

Comment: @Serigy Nenko Hopefully the issue will be reported in sever php error log.you can check it there

Comment: @Mageotron. I checked in server php error log it's not have any messages for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify your Magento version too.

Anyway, for 1 series, the logs are at `var/system.log` or `var/exception.log`.

Note the relative path, they are not absolute.

Comment: my Magento's version is 1.9.2.4

Comment: Then as I said, look into those files.